# Periodically log the content of a file using setInterval and FileReader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, filereader

I'm attaching this f-tion to an `<input type="file">` element as an "onclick" handler:

```
handleWatch(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  if (!file) {
    return;
  }

  const reader = new FileReader();

  setInterval(() => {

    reader.onload = async function(e) {
      const content = e.target.result;

      const lines = content.split('\n').filter((line) => {
        return !line.beginsWith('#') && !(line === "");
      });
      const nLines = lines.length - 1;

      console.log("number of lines in file: " + nLines);

    }
    reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');

  }, 1500);

}
```

The idea is to create a logger which periodically checks the content of file (selected by user) for changes and persists to DB (this code removed for clarity). Interval execution works (logs to console), up to a point when the content is indeed changed, then none of the instructions inside reader.onload are executed.

Answer (score 1):

From the FileAPI specification you can read here: https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#security-discussion

> Important security considerations include preventing malicious file
>   selection attacks (selection looping), preventing access to
>   system-sensitive files, **and guarding against modifications of files
>   on disk after a selection has taken place.**

Since this section is informative it is possible that this security feature is not implemented in all browsers. It seems the browser you are using is following the specification (and I guess all are).

We can also read this:

> This is a non-trivial requirement to implement for user agents, and is
>   thus not a must but a should [RFC2119]. User agents should endeavor to
>   have a File object's snapshot state set to the state of the underlying
>   storage on disk at the time the reference is taken. If the file is
>   modified on disk following the time a reference has been taken, the
>   File's snapshot state will differ from the state of the underlying
>   storage. User agents may use modification time stamps and other
>   mechanisms to maintain snapshot state, but this is left as an
>   implementation detail.

So even a browser was not blocking you after the file has changed then you would get a snapshot of the file when the user selected the file.

Comment: Well, that's a show stopper. Could fs.FileWatch() help here?

Comment: I guess you are referring to the node module file system ?. It is not available in browsers. (there are some ports but they use virtual file systems not the one of the user's comptuer)